Prevent Form Submission If Field Is Invalid (For multi field forms)
OK. I have this form where I call forth an error if validation fails on submission. Problem is, it still submits to the server anyway.
I still get an alert error message for each field that fails validation. But then it submits to the server anyway. Except if its the last field that fails validation. In that case, I get the error message and it doesn’t submit.
I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I've been able to prevent submission for each field when I put it in a single HTML file.  But not when I put all the fields together in a HTML file.
Most of my prior form validations have been single field forms.
What am I doing wrong?
My HTML:
"
<form name="locationForm" action="https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php" target="_blank" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post"> 
<label for="strname">Street Or PO Box Address:</label>
<input type="text" id="strname" name="strname"><br><br> 

<label for="cityname">City:</label> 
<input type="text" id="cityname" name="cityname"><br><br>

<label for="statename">State ( or territory ):</label>
<select id="statename" name="statename"> 
<option value="">Please pick your state or territory of residence:</option>
<option value="Alabama">AL</option>
<option value="Alaska">AK</option>
<option value="Arizona">AZ</option>
<option value="Arkansas">AR</option> 
<option value="California">CA</option> 
<option value="Colorado">CO</option> 
<option value="Connecticut">CT</option> 
<option value="Delaware">DE</option> 
<option value="Florida">FL</option> 
<option value="Georgia">GA</option> 
<option value="Hawaii">HI</option> 
<option value="Idaho">ID</option> 
<option value="Illinois">IL</option> 
<option value="Indiana">IN</option> 
<option value="Iowa">IA</option> 
<option value="Kansas">KS</option> 
<option value="Kentucky">KY</option> 
<option value="Louisiana">LA</option> 
<option value="Maine">ME</option> 
<option value="Maryland">MD</option> 
<option value="Massachusetts">MA</option> 
<option value="Michigan">MI</option> 
<option value="Minnesota">MN</option> 
<option value="Mississippi">MS</option> 
<option value="Missouri">MO</option> 
<option value="Montana">MT</option> 
<option value="Nebraska">NE</option> 
<option value="Nevada">NV</option> 
<option value="New Hampshire">NH</option> 
<option value="New Jersey">NJ</option> 
<option value="New Mexico">NM</option> 
<option value="New York">NY</option> 
<option value="North Carolina">NC</option> 
<option value="North Dakota">ND</option> 
<option value="Ohio">OH</option>
<option value="Oklahoma">OK</option> 
<option value="Oregon">OR</option> 
<option value="Pennsylvania">PA</option> 
<option value="Rhode Island">RI</option> 
<option value="South Carolina">SC</option>
<option value="South Dakota">SD</option> 
<option value="Tennessee">TN</option> 
<option value="Texas">TX</option> 
<option value="Utah">UT</option> 
<option value="Vermont">VT</option>
<option value="Virginia">VA</option> 
<option value="Washington">WA</option>
<option value="West Virginia">WV</option>
<option value="Wisconsin">WI</option>
<option value="Wyoming">WY</option>
<option value="District Of Columbia">DC</option>
<option value="American Samoa">AS</option> 
<option value="Guam">GU</option>
<option value="Northern Mariana Islands">MP</option> 
<option value="Puerto Rico">PR</option> 
<option value="US Virgin Islands">VI</option>
</select><br><br>

<label for="zipcode">Zip Code:</label> 
<input type="number" id="zipcode" name="zipcode"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form> 

<script> 
function validateForm() { 
valid = true;

let w = /^([0-9A-Za-z]+\s)+([0-9A-Za-z]+\s)+([0-9A-Za-z]+\s)+([0-9A-Za-z])+|([A-Z]+\s)+([A-Za-z]+\s)+([0-9]+)$/;
if ( document.locationForm.strname.value == "" ) { 
alert ( "Physical ( street or PO ) address cannot be blank" ); 
valid = false; 
} 

else if ( document.locationForm.strname.value.match ( w ) ) 
{ valid = true; } 

else { 
alert ( "A physical address can only have letters and numbers with spaces between them" ); 
valid = false; 
}

let x = /^[A-Za-z]+$/; 
if ( document.locationForm.cityname.value == "" ) { 
alert ( "City name cannot be blank" ); 
valid = false; 
}

else if ( document.locationForm.cityname.value.match ( x ) ) 
{ valid = true; } 

else { 
alert ( "A city name can only have letters in it." ); 
valid = false; 
}

if ( document.locationForm.statename.selectedIndex == 0 ) {
alert ( "What state or territory do you live in?" ); 
valid = false; 
} 

else if ( document.locationForm.statename.selectedIndex != 0 ) { 
valid = true; 
} 

let z = /^[0-9]{5}$/; 
if ( document.locationForm.zipcode.value == "" ) { 
alert ( "Zip code cannot be blank" ); 
valid = false; 
} 

else if ( document.locationForm.zipcode.value.match ( z ) ) 
{ valid = true; } 

else { 
alert ( "Zip code must have exactly five digits." ); 
valid = false; 
}
return valid; 
} 
</script>

</body> 
</html>

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I've been able to prevent submission for each field when I put it in a single HTML file.  But not when I put all the fields together in a HTML file.
Most of my prior form validations have been single field forms.

well you're setting valid to true if any of the fields are valid. You don't want to set it to true if its already false (due to a previous field being invalid)

This answer gets me halfway there.  Now I only have "valid = true" at the start of the validation.  And I get an alert if any of the fields are left blank.  But if I put garbage in a  field (less than 5 digits for zip code, or special characters in with alphabetical characters for city name, for examples), the form still submits as long as all the fields have something in them.  So I'm still doing something wrong...

You can use the build-in form validation of the browser. Here, I add the different messages as attributes on each form field, and use the value to display a custom error message to the user.
The form will not submit as long as all the required form fields are not valid. Validation is based on the evaluation of the pattern, min and max attributes on the different form fields.


document.locationForm.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  let message = (e.target.value == '') ? e.target.dataset.blank : e.target.title;
  e.target.setCustomValidity(message);
}, true);
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 1em;
}
<form name="locationForm" action="/location.php" method="post">
  <label>Street Or PO Box Address: <input type="text" name="strname" pattern="[0-9A-Za-z]+[0-9A-Za-z\s]+" title="A physical address can only have letters and numbers with spaces between them" data-blank="Physical ( street or PO ) address cannot be blank" required></label>

  <label>City: <input type="text" name="cityname" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="A physical address can only have letters and numbers with spaces between them" data-blank="City name cannot be blank" required></label>

  <label>State ( or territory ): <select name="statename" title="What state or territory do you live in?" data-blank="What state or territory do you live in?" required>
    <option value="">Please pick your state or territory of residence:</option>
    <option value="Alabama">AL</option>
    <option value="Alaska">AK</option>
    <option value="Arizona">AZ</option>
    <option value="Arkansas">AR</option>
    <option value="California">CA</option>
    <option value="Colorado">CO</option>
    <option value="Connecticut">CT</option>
    <option value="Delaware">DE</option>
    <option value="Florida">FL</option>
    <option value="Georgia">GA</option>
    <option value="Hawaii">HI</option>
    <option value="Idaho">ID</option>
    <option value="Illinois">IL</option>
    <option value="Indiana">IN</option>
    <option value="Iowa">IA</option>
    <option value="Kansas">KS</option>
    <option value="Kentucky">KY</option>
    <option value="Louisiana">LA</option>
    <option value="Maine">ME</option>
    <option value="Maryland">MD</option>
    <option value="Massachusetts">MA</option>
    <option value="Michigan">MI</option>
    <option value="Minnesota">MN</option>
    <option value="Mississippi">MS</option>
    <option value="Missouri">MO</option>
    <option value="Montana">MT</option>
    <option value="Nebraska">NE</option>
    <option value="Nevada">NV</option>
    <option value="New Hampshire">NH</option>
    <option value="New Jersey">NJ</option>
    <option value="New Mexico">NM</option>
    <option value="New York">NY</option>
    <option value="North Carolina">NC</option>
    <option value="North Dakota">ND</option>
    <option value="Ohio">OH</option>
    <option value="Oklahoma">OK</option>
    <option value="Oregon">OR</option>
    <option value="Pennsylvania">PA</option>
    <option value="Rhode Island">RI</option>
    <option value="South Carolina">SC</option>
    <option value="South Dakota">SD</option>
    <option value="Tennessee">TN</option>
    <option value="Texas">TX</option>
    <option value="Utah">UT</option>
    <option value="Vermont">VT</option>
    <option value="Virginia">VA</option>
    <option value="Washington">WA</option>
    <option value="West Virginia">WV</option>
    <option value="Wisconsin">WI</option>
    <option value="Wyoming">WY</option>
    <option value="District Of Columbia">DC</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">AS</option>
    <option value="Guam">GU</option>
    <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">MP</option>
    <option value="Puerto Rico">PR</option>
    <option value="US Virgin Islands">VI</option>
  </select></label>
  <label>Zip Code: <input type="number" name="zipcode" min="10000" max="99999" title="Zip code must have exactly five digits" data-blank="Zip code cannot be blank" required></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



